# How can I pass the class of my parameter to another method call?

Tags: java, generics, jax-rs, cxf

I'm creating a method that will make calls to [`JAXRSClientFactory`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactory.html) as shown below.

```
public T create(Class<T> resourceType) throws Exception {
    Class<T> resource = JAXRSClientFactory.create(basePath, resourceType.getClass(), username, password, null);
    // do common configuration for any interface T
    Client client = WebClient.client(resource);
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.fromClient(client);
    SSLUtil.configure(webClient);
    return resource.newInstance();
}
```

However, this isn't working as I expected because `resourceType.getClass()` returns `java.lang.Class` and not the class of `T`.

Changing the call to `JAXRSClientFactory` to use `resourceType` instead results in the following incompatible types error:

[image: incompatible types error screenshot]

How can I modify this method so that I can pass the class of `T` to `JAXRSClientFactory.create()`?

Comment: Just use `resourceType`

Comment: Nevermind, I don't use CXF, but looking at the API for [`JAXRSClientFactory`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactory.html), I see your problem

Comment: I think you are missing how the API is supposed to be used. The factory class creates a proxy from your interface. And you use the interface to make the call. So you should use the `resourceType` as the argument, and make the call with the returned proxy. You don't instantiate the class

Comment: `resourceType` is the interface and therefore the expected return type

Comment: All the `JAXRSClientFactory.create` methods return `T` which is an instance of the class passed to it. And that's what you want to make the proxy call. Currently your method doesn't make any call

Comment: I've never worked with CXF Client, but I _have_ worked with both the RESTeasy client proxy support, and Jersey client proxy support, and this is how both of them work. And looking at the docs for `JAXRSClientFactory`, all the methods mention the creatation of a proxy, so I would imagine it works exactly the same

Comment: I guess I should explain.  So I want to do some common configuration for every `SomeResource` I create.  I've removed the lines now but they would be done between the call to the factory and the return statement.  I thought I could do this by proxying the calls to `JAXRSClientFactory` by allowing a generic argument that I could construct a client for any provided interface.  But I can't figure out how to then pass that interface type into `JAXRSClientFactory`.  I guess I can do the call to the factory and then separately configure it, it's just not as clean.

Comment: Why can't you just do `return  JAXRSClientFactory.create(.., resourceType..)`. That will return the instance of the proxy client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [JAXRSClientFactory#create(String, Class, String, String, String)](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactory.html#create(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> **Parameters:**
>
> `baseAddress` - baseAddress
>   `cls` - proxy class, if not interface then a CGLIB proxy will be created
>   `username` - username
>   `password` - password
>   `configLocation` - classpath location of the configuration resource
>
> **Returns:**
>
> typed proxy

Your modified code:

```
public T create(Class<T> resourceType) throws Exception {
    T resource = JAXRSClientFactory.create(basePath, resourceType, username, password, null);
    Client client = WebClient.client(resource);
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.fromClient(client);
    SSLUtil.configure(webClient);
    return resource;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`resourceType.getClass()` will always return a `Class<Class>` result, instead of `<Class<T>`.

Since you already have the `Class<T>` as a parameter, then you should probably do:

```
T resource = JAXRSClientFactory.create(basePath, resourceType, username, password, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that the parameter `Class<T> resourceType` is an instance of T.  This is wrong.

The parameter definition of `Class<T> resourceType` does *not* define `resourceType` as an instance of `T`, but as the class of `T` (i.e., an instance of `Class` which is `T.class`).

Therefore, because `resourceType` is an instance of class, calling `resourceType.getClass()` returns `Class.class`.

If you want the parameter to be an instance of T, you would need the method signature to be:

```
public T create(T resourceType)
```

But in reality, I suspect you probably do want the Class, not an instance, so you should change the call to `JAXRSClientFactory.create` to:

```
T resource = JAXRSClientFactory.create(basePath, resourceType, username, password, null);
```